Use a custom control Navigation Bar in Maui Shell
Can the default Shell navigation bar be replaced with a custom control? I have the code for a Title View here that I would like to use:
https://github.com/syncfusion/essential-ui-kit-for-xamarin.forms/blob/master/EssentialUIKit/Controls/TitleView.cs
But haven't quite figured out where and how to replace the Nav bar, hook up the burger menu etc. In the contentpage I tried
 <NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <controls:TitleView Title="Test"></controls:TitleView>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>

The closest thing to customization that I have found is
https://blog.ewers-peters.de/customize-the-title-bar-of-a-maui-app-with-these-simple-steps
But that has problems of its own, specifically centering the Title text while having a trailing icon as well.

I have converted your xamarin forms code in the github link to the maui. And it worked in the .net maui. There are some points:

Grid.Children.Add has been to changed as Grid.Add. Such as this.Add(boxView, 0, 1);.
The SetColumnSpan(boxView, 5) need to declare parameter: SetColumnSpan(view: boxView, 5)

You can just copy your code into maui project and change it as the code above. And then use the TitleView in the AppShell.xaml:
<Shell.TitleView>
    <controls:TitleView Title="Test"></controls:TitleView>
</Shell.TitleView>

In addition, there is blank space at the left side on the android. Adding the following code in the App class's constructor can fix it:
         public App()
         {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ToolbarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomNavigationView", (handler, view) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.ContentInsetStartWithNavigation = 0;
            handler.PlatformView.SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
#endif
            });

            InitializeComponent();
          }

And for the iOS, you can refer to this pull request:[iOS] Shell/NavigationPage TitleView.
